# How to retrieve the current post index number in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Is there a way to get the current post index number from **site.posts**?

**{{ site.posts | size }}** is the total number of posts.
What I need is something like **{{ site.posts.index }}** or **{{ page.index }}**.

I am trying to display a counter on each post page. Example: **Post 43 of 2654**

Answer (score 12):

In a `for` loop you can get current item index in two ways :

```
{% for post in site.posts %}{{ forloop.index }}{% endfor %}
# will print 123...
```

or

```
{% for post in site.posts %}{{ forloop.index0 }}{% endfor %}
# will print 012...
```

And what you need is `{{ forloop.index }}`

Comment: It works but looping all posts for every single post to find the index is way too expensive and makes generation prohibitively long unfortunately. Any other idea? Any way to programmatically add an index number to the front matter maybe?

Answer (score 6):

(Answering my own question, maybe it helps someone else)

There is indeed another way (and without a major performance hit) using a simple jekyll plugin:

```
module Jekyll
    class PostIndex < Generator
        safe true
        priority :low
        def generate(site)
            site.posts.each_with_index do |item, index|
                item.data['index'] = index
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Save as ***post_index_generator.rb*** and place in ***_plugins*** folder.

Get the post index in the template with ***{{ page.index }}***

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Any ideas how to modernize it?

Comment: Since 2014 there's a deprecation, although your version works still as well `Deprecation: posts.each_with_index should be changed to posts.docs.each_with_index.`

Comment: Will this work with GitHub gh-pages? I mean custom plugins.

Comment: For gh-pages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215356/jekyll-how-to-use-custom-plugins-with-github-pages